# Entity с полями LocalDate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть `Entity` класс, содержащий поля с типом `LocalDate`. Добавил для них аннотацию `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`, но при запуске приложения выдает ошибку:

> TemporalJavaType(javaType=java.time.LocalDate) as
> `jakarta.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` not supported

Можно ли как-то записывать поля с таким типом в БД `Postgres`?

Нашел такое решение вместо `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` использовать

```
@Column (columnDefinition = "DATE")
```

правильно ли это?

Comment: Такой тип не поддерживается, попробуй DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать аннотацию `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.DATE)`